# preventDefault on a div parent prevent an input child from getting focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div that contains a Text Input. On mousedown of that div I need to prevent default, but when I click the input to type in some text it doesn't get focus because of the div (parent) prevent default.

HTML

```
<div class="test">
    <input type="text" class="input1" />
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(".test").on('mousedown', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Is it possible to solve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `e.stopPropagation();` for the input. It will stop the event from propagating to parent `div`.

```js
$(".test").on('mousedown', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
$(".test input").on('mousedown', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
    <input type="text" class="input1" />
</div>
```

But if you use `click` event, then this wont be an issue. Event will be propagated, but the focus wont be lost.

```js
$(".test").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
    <input type="text" class="input1" />
</div>
```

Comment: the other answers works but I choose this solution because when the input get the focus then I click the parent div, it trigger the blur on the input automatically, while the other solutions (testing for e.target) doesn't trigger blur when I click out the input. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Test `e.target`, if it is the input, don't `preventDefault()`.

Comment: But I am very eager to know why the focus is getting cancelled?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy — Because that is the default behavior of clicking on an input.